# How to Create a Search Scope?

Tags: document-library, search-scope

I have following scenario. Could you please suggest how to create/configure a custom Scope.

site is purchasing and document library is procurement

Procurement library is only available to site members but not to the whole company. So I set "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results" to No.

I created a custom Scope for the purchasing site.

> Include http://something.site/Purchashing/Procurement
>
> Required IsDocument=1
>
> Exclude http://something.site/Purchashing/Procurement/Forms

Total shows 0

Search result on the Purchasing site for this scope returns nothing.

What is the best to way to handle this where NO one in the company can see result from this library but when a search is performed from Purchashing search site and scope is automatically set to "Procurement Only" then result will show for Site Users.

Comment: I just thought of something. If the document library's permission is well set then it would not show up in global search due to security trim. therefore, setting "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results" to "Yes" should do the trick. I really need a second pair of eyes on this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. If your library is not for everyone, do NOT un-check for Search availability, but rather change its security to include either appropriate site groups (recommanded) or persons. It is the recommanded course of actions as Search is security trimming results.
2. There 2 different types of Search Scopes -Site Collection level and Farm Level (Shared Search Scope). In your situation you might want to do it as Site Collection level as this will not require intervention from SharePoint Farm Admin.

These being said, you could create a site collection level search scope and in the Inclusion Rules use Web Address and specify the actual Library (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/define-scopes-for-searches-HA010241119.aspx#BMha10241119_secaddeditscoperules). THe reason you might not see results is also because you disabled "Appear in Search Results" and you would need to wait for the Crawl after re-enabling it.